# Почему parseInt от array = ['1','1','1'] возвращает 1?

Tags: javascript

Почему parseInt от array возвращает 1, а не все числа массива?

```
let array = ['1','1','1'];
parseInt(array);
```

Comment: @Grundy в дубликате про массивы ни слова

Comment: @АлексейШиманский. да, там описывается работа самих функций и подчеркивается, что в случае `parseInt` аргумент **всегда** приводится к строке и берется не вся строка, а только часть, с допустимыми символами.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Массив изначально будет приведён к строке. Строковое представление плоского массива - элементы, перечисленные через запятую. Получаем следующую строку:

```
'1,1,1,1'
```

Очевидно, что как только `parseInt` доходит до первого не числового значения (запятой), он откидывает всё, что после него, включая сам нечисловой символ. В итоге возвращается первая единица

Comment: Большое спасибо за понятное объяснение!